# WPF UserControl with DependencyObject binding

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Here's what I want to accomplish:

```
<ctrl:MyControl x:Name="mc">
    <ctrl:MyControl.MyData>
        <ctrl:MyDataCollection>
            <ctrl:MyData MyProperty="{Binding PropertyA}"/>
            <ctrl:MyData MyProperty="{Binding PropertyB}"/>
        </ctrl:MyDataCollection>
    </ctrl:MyControl.MyData>
</ctrl:MyControl>
```

MyDataCollection is simply:

```
public class MyDataCollection : List<MyData>
{
};
```

And MyData:

```
public class MyData : DependencyObject
{

    public MyData()
    {

    }

    public double MyProperty
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(double), typeof(MyData), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
}
```

MyCotrol contains DependencyProperty of MyDataCollection.
Now to the point. MyDataCollection is filled correctly with MyData, problem lies with MyProperty in MyData not binding (MyProperty got default value). If I set it by hand(for instance MyProperty="5") everything works fine.

My MVVM implements INotifyPropertyChanged, It got two Properties, PropertyA and PropertyB and is set as DataContext of MyControl.

Any ideas what I am missing? I was able to do this with UserControl, but I can't get it to work with DependencyObject inside UserControl.

EDIT:

I added dependency property in MyControl, then I did:

```
<ctrl:MyControl x:Name="mc" TestProperty ="{Binding PropertyA}">
    <ctrl:MyControl.MyData>
        <ctrl:MyDataCollection>
            <ctrl:MyData MyProperty="{Binding PropertyB}"/>
        </ctrl:MyDataCollection>
    </ctrl:MyControl.MyData>
</ctrl:MyControl>
```

And it works perfectly for TestProperty.

Error from output panel:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but ... does it work if you use `MyProperty="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ctrl:MyControl},Path=DataContext.PropertyA}"` ?  That would imply `DataContext` is not being inherited by `MyData`.

Comment: Also, can you check the output pane for any binding errors ... might be helpful.